# Multi-channel data transmission system for Pixhawk autopilot

Tags: i2c, can, bus, transmission

I hope to connect multiple [Pixhawk autopilots](https://pixhawk.org/modules/pixhawk) to one PC, to establish a simulation system. In case you are unfamiliar with Pixhawk autopilot, here is a brief introduction:

> **Pixhawk autopilot** is an STM32F4 based controller for unmanned aerial vehicles. It is equipped with interfaces including UART, CAN, SPI, I²C, et al.

Now I have up to 50 Pixhawks, and I want to connect them with one PC. The data transmission between Pixhawk and PC needs to satisfy:

- Each Pixhawk sending data @6.4 kbit/s and receiving data @25.6 kbit/s, at least.
- The PC needs to distinguish who the sender is, i.e. to distinguish which Pixhawk sent a certain datagram.

Since the add-on development of Pixhawk is hard, I am not going to use the CAN or I²C interface of the Pixhawk. My plan is, to add another chip or board between a Pixhawk and PC, just like:

[image]

So, my question is:

- What chip should I choose to finish this task?
- Is the UART communication between Pixhawk and the chip okay?
- What kind of bus should I choose?

Comment: You mention "aerial vehicles". Is any of this data going to be wireless? The data transfer reliability and thus protocol is greatly affected by that.

Comment: @Oldfart This is just a simulation system. If required by reliability, I can tolerate any wireless part of this system being replaced by a wired solution.

Comment: Why is this question tagged with `i2c` and `can` if you don't intend to use either of them?

Comment: Unless it is a mission-critical system, Ethernet might be the best choice. Depending on how much and how often you send data, CAN may or may not be able to handle the necessary bandwidth.

Comment: "Is the UART communication between Pixhawk and the chip okay?" What kind of question is that? It is your design, you tell us. Nobody knows what "chip" is.